# AngularJS Select Box Pre-select when array is an object

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of objects and when i go to populate the select with the elements, it doesn't pre-select the currently active one.  If i change the select it all works as intended, but the pre-selected element is not selected on page load.

**JS**:

```
$scope.license_year_list = [
    {label:"Year of 1991", value:1991}, 
    {label:"Year of 1992", value:1992}  ];

$scope.item = {license_year: {label:"Year of 1992", value:1992}};
```

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="item.license_year" 
            ng-options="y.label for y in license_year_list">
    </select>
</div>
```

**Fiddle**:
http://jsfiddle.net/eXvH8/

Comment: with angular 1.1.5+ [`y.label for y in license_year_list track by y.value`](http://jsbin.com/EXukAGo/1/) would have worked too. And [this](http://jsbin.com/awACUnU/1/) could be used to directly work with the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality of the objects are evaluated by reference, so you need use the exactly same object when you want to select it.

```
$scope.item = {
    license_year: $scope.license_year_list[1]
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Angular checks for equality based on reference of the actual object/value. To make your select box start out with the default value, do a simple assignment of the default value. Change your code like this:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<select ng-model="item" ng-options="y.label for y in license_year_list"></select>

<br/><br/><br/>
{{item.license_year}}
</div>
```

JS:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.license_year_list = [{label:"Year of 1991", value:1991}, {label:"Year of 1992", value:1992}];

$scope.item = $scope.license_year_list[1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks ~ The $scope.item definition is a little wrong, it still needs to be an object where the license_year is your value.